# Javascript array remove every other element

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm looking for a way to remove array other elements.
But I don't know how to do it.

This is my array:

```
musics: [
          {
            id: 1,
            cover: require('~/assets/images/cover/music/ali_zand_vakili_jadeh_shab.jpg'),
            title: 'جاده شب',
            artist: 'علی زند وکیلی',
            source: 'http://media.mtvpersian.net/2019/Mar/21/Ali%20Zand%20Vakili%20-%20Jadeh%20Shab.mp3'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            cover: require('~/assets/images/cover/music/amin_hayaei_divoone_misazi.jpg'),
            title: 'دیوونه میسازی',
            artist: 'امین حیایی',
            source: 'https://cdnmrtehran.ir/media/mp3s_128/Amin_Hayaei/Singles/amin_hayaei_divoone_misazi.mp3'
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            cover: require('~/assets/images/cover/music/emad_talebzadeh_maghrour.jpg'),
            title: 'مغرور',
            artist: 'عماد طالب زاده',
            source: 'https://cdnmrtehran.ir/media/mp3s_128/Emad_Talebzadeh/Singles/emad_talebzadeh_maghrour.mp3'
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            cover: require('~/assets/images/cover/music/farzad_farzin_jazzab.jpg'),
            title: 'جذاب',
            artist: 'فرزاد فرزین',
            source: 'https://cdnmrtehran.ir/media/mp3s_128/Farzad_Farzin/Singles/farzad_farzin_jazzab.mp3'
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            cover: require('~/assets/images/cover/music/hamid_sefat_ajayeb_shahr_merat_remix.jpg'),
            title: 'عجایب شهر رمیکس',
            artist: 'حمید صفت',
            source: 'https://cdnmrtehran.ir/media/mp3s_128/Hamid_Sefat/Singles/hamid_sefat_ajayeb_shahr_merat_remix.mp3'
          }
        ],
```

How to remove all elements except element with id of 3 ?

Comment: You've asked 2 different questions here so you might want to clarify what result you're going for. Either way you'll probably want to use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: how to do it with filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var musics= [{id: 1,cover: '~/assets/images/cover/music/ali_zand_vakili_jadeh_shab.jpg',title: 'جاده شب',artist: 'علی زند وکیلی',source: 'http://media.mtvpersian.net/2019/Mar/21/Ali%20Zand%20Vakili%20-%20Jadeh%20Shab.mp3'},
{id: 2,cover: '~/assets/images/cover/music/amin_hayaei_divoone_misazi.jpg',title: 'دیوونه میسازی',artist: 'امین حیایی',source: 'https://cdnmrtehran.ir/media/mp3s_128/Amin_Hayaei/Singles/amin_hayaei_divoone_misazi.mp3'},
{id: 3,cover: '~/assets/images/cover/music/emad_talebzadeh_maghrour.jpg',title: 'مغرور',artist: 'عماد طالب زاده',source: 'https://cdnmrtehran.ir/media/mp3s_128/Emad_Talebzadeh/Singles/emad_talebzadeh_maghrour.mp3'},
{id: 4,cover: '~/assets/images/cover/music/farzad_farzin_jazzab.jpg',title: 'جذاب',artist: 'فرزاد فرزین',source: 'https://cdnmrtehran.ir/media/mp3s_128/Farzad_Farzin/Singles/farzad_farzin_jazzab.mp3'},
{id: 5,cover:'~/assets/images/cover/music/hamid_sefat_ajayeb_shahr_merat_remix.jpg',title: 'عجایب شهر رمیکس',artist: 'حمید صفت',source: 'https://cdnmrtehran.ir/media/mp3s_128/Hamid_Sefat/Singles/hamid_sefat_ajayeb_shahr_merat_remix.mp3'}]

var result =[];

musics.forEach(function(item){
  if(item.id == 3){
   result.push(item);
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: return in `forEach` doesn't makes sense, you should just use `if( item.id === 3) { result.push(item); }` instead of if else, moreover OP wants to remove all the elements except the ones which has `id` as 3

Comment: @CodeManiac You are right , I dont know what i was thinking while posting answer sorry for it , and thanks for help :) I Corrected my mistake

Answer (score 4):

To remove all the even indexed elements you could use the following:

```js
musics = musics.filter((e, i) =>  i % 2 == 0)
```

To remove the odd ones simply change the == with !=

Comment: `filter` creates a new array with all of the elements of this array for which the provided filtering function returns `true`. Therefore `i % 2 == 0` would keep *even* indexed elements and would remove *odd* indexed ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
musics = musics.filter (x => x.id == 3)
```